# Missing instances for ResourceT in conduit

Tags: haskell, instance, conduit

I'm getting a strange error when trying to use [`ResourceT`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/conduit-1.0.9.1/docs/Data-Conduit.html#t%3aResourceT) from conduit 1.0.9.1. I'm missing instances from the documentation. For example

```
import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.Trans
import Control.Monad.IO.Class
import Data.Conduit

test = runResourceT (lift $ print "Hello world")
```

fails with *No instance for (`MonadTrans ResourceT`) arising from a use of `lift`*, although there are many instances in the docs, including `MonadTrans ResourceT`. Checking REPL confirms the problem:

```
Prelude> :m Data.Conduit
Prelude Data.Conduit> :i ResourceT
newtype ResourceT m a
  = Control.Monad.Trans.Resource.Internal.ResourceT ...
-- Defined in `Control.Monad.Trans.Resource.Internal'
instance Monad m => Monad (ResourceT m)
  -- Defined in `Control.Monad.Trans.Resource.Internal'
instance Functor m => Functor (ResourceT m)
  -- Defined in `Control.Monad.Trans.Resource.Internal'
instance MonadThrow m => MonadThrow (ResourceT m)
  -- Defined in `Control.Monad.Trans.Resource.Internal'
instance MonadBaseControl b m => MonadBaseControl b (ResourceT m)
  -- Defined in `Control.Monad.Trans.Resource.Internal'
```

This seems like some stupid mistake on my side, but I can't figure it out. Where are the missing instances?

Comment: The usual cause of this is having multiple versions of some package installed - either mtl, transformers, or conduit.

Comment: Works fine for me when I specified conduit==1.0.9.1, transformers==0.3.0.0, and mtl==2.1.2, but @Carl is correct, this appears to be caused by depending on both transformers and mtl, causing conflicts

Comment: Perhaps `Data.Conduit` did not always export the instances?