# Missing instance MonadIO for ConduitM?

Tags: haskell, conduit

According to [the documentation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/conduit-1.1.3/docs/Data-Conduit.html) there is a `MonadIO` instance for ConduitM if the underlying Monad has a `MonadIO` instance (`MonadIO m => MonadIO (ConduitM i o m)`).

Why then does this:

```
yield (1::Int) $$ await >>= (liftIO.print) :: IO ()
```

fail with this:

> > No instance for (MonadIO (ConduitM Int Data.Void.Void IO))
> >           arising from a use of ‘liftIO’
> >         In the first argument of ‘(.)’, namely ‘liftIO’
> >         In the second argument of ‘(>>=)’, namely ‘(liftIO . print)’
> >         In the second argument of ‘($$)’, namely
> >           ‘await >>= (liftIO . print)’

What am I missing here?

---

Just checked, apparently I have both transformers 0.22 and transformers 0.3, that might be the cause.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was that conduit depends on transformers-0.2.2.1 (for some reason) and I had both that and transformers-0.3.0.0 - hiding transformers-0.3.0.0 fixed this for now (if I had used cabal it probably would've worked too). In effect, this was the same problem as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20121467/missing-instances-for-resourcet-in-conduit?rq=1).